# Saving a class variable as a number

Tags: python, python-class

Want to use class to make my code concise and easier to pass around to others.

```
class distance:
     .05 = x
     .10 = y
     .15 = z
...
```

I can't name something a number is there a way to get around this.

Comment: Why is the other way around bad, `variable_name = value`? Then others can access values via the variable names.

Comment: What is the reason for naming something a number? What is you intention? Is the goal to say that `.05` took `x` amount of time?

Comment: "I can't name something a number" - indeed, a number cannot be a variable name, and nothing can be done about it

Comment: How does your second sentence relate to the first?

Comment: Hi, welcome! As other users have said, Python simply requires variables to start with a letter or underscore (a long with a few other constraints). If you wanted to do something very similar to what you're currently doing, you could try using _05, _10 & _15. However, as other users have said, it's probably better to think up names which can be better understood by someone reading your code, like us!